# TensorFlow: Evaluating functions across a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

Sci-Py lets me do the following with the norm.pdf function:

```
x = 1;  
mu = [1,2,3,4];
sigma = [1,1,1,1];
scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x,mu,sigma)
```

This will basically give me an array, where each element corresponds to the probability density of x given the corresponding mean and variance.

I'm trying to do this, with the difference being that x, mu, and var are now tensors (x is rank-0, mu and var are rank 1 tensors). I want norm.pdf to be a rank 1 tensor as well. I'm trying to do this on TensorFlow but not sure how to.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TensorFlow, you can do it in 2 steps with [`tf.contrib.distributions.Normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/contrib.distributions/univariate__scalar__distributions#Normal) and [`tf.contrib.distributions.Distribution.pdf`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/contrib.distributions/base_classes#Distribution.pdf)

```
# Define a batch of 4 scalar valued Normals (mu=means, sigma=standard deviations)
dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(mu=[1,2,3,4], sigma=[1,1,1,1])

# Evaluate the pdf of the first distribution on 1
# returning a length two tensor.
dist.pdf(1)
```